# Why does Python pandas read_csv not work when combined with other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Python pandas `read_csv` gives correct output when written individually like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def bgp_neighbor_status():
    data = pd.read_csv('E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-result.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row[9] == 'Down' or row[9] == 'Idle' or row[9] == 'Active':
            print(f"Neighbor {row[0]} is down")
        else:
            pass

bgp_neighbor_status()
```

Output which is showing as expected:

```
Neighbor 10.0.11.101 is down
```

However, when I combine the same function with another function like this I am getting the error:- **pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd

import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko
import re

bgp_result_file = open(r'E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-result.txt','w')
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = bgp_result_file
platform = 'cisco_ios'
username = 'javed'
password = 'cisco'

ip_add_file = open(r'E:\\Python-Scripts\\IPAddressList.txt', 'r')

def check_bgp(ip_add_file):

    for host in ip_add_file:
        host = host.rstrip('\n')
        connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
        output = connect.send_command('terminal length 0')
        output = connect.send_command('enable')
        bgp_status = connect.send_command('show ip bgp summary | be N')
        print (bgp_status)


def bgp_neighbor_status():
    data = pd.read_csv('E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-result.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if row[9] == 'Down' or row[9] == 'Idle' or row[9] == 'Active':
            print(f"Neighbor {row[0]} is down")
        else:
            pass

check_bgp(ip_add_file)
bgp_neighbor_status()
```

Comment: Because `bgp_result_file = open(r'E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-result.txt','w')` opens the file in write mode and deletes its entire contents right at the beginning of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here right at the top:

`bgp_result_file = open(r'E:\\Python-Scripts\\bgp-result.txt','w')`

That line is executed at the start of your script and basically wipes out the file. From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

> The most commonly-used values of mode are 'r' for reading, 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position). [...]

*truncating the file if it already exists*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it started working after changing, 'w' to ;'r+'